# plotly: 3D plotting returns a figure with no datapoints

Tags: python-3.x, plotly, k-means

Trying to plot results from K-means clustering using 3D plot (Plotly). There is a blank figure generated in the HTML  when I use the below code. I printed the variables scatter 1,2,3 and also the cluster 1,2,3 and values are shown. Is there a plt.show() like in matplotlib in plotly to show the values in the graph?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import argparse
import json
import re
import os
import sys
import plotly
import plotly.graph_objs as go

cluster1=df.loc[df['y'] == 0]
cluster2=df.loc[df['y'] == 1]
cluster3=df.loc[df['y'] == 2]

scatter1 = dict(
    mode = "markers",
    name = "Cluster 1",
    type = "scatter3d",    
    x = cluster1.as_matrix()[:,0], y = cluster1.as_matrix()[:,1], z = cluster1.as_matrix()[:,2],
    marker = dict( size=2, color='green')
)
scatter2 = dict(
    mode = "markers",
    name = "Cluster 2",
    type = "scatter3d",    
    x = cluster2.as_matrix()[:,0], y = cluster2.as_matrix()[:,1], z = cluster2.as_matrix()[:,2],
    marker = dict( size=2, color='blue')
)
scatter3 = dict(
    mode = "markers",
    name = "Cluster 3",
    type = "scatter3d",    
    x = cluster3.as_matrix()[:,0], y = cluster3.as_matrix()[:,1], z = cluster3.as_matrix()[:,2],
    marker = dict( size=2, color='red')
)
cluster1 = dict(
    alphahull = 5,
    name = "Cluster 1",
    opacity = .1,
    type = "mesh3d",    
    x = cluster1.as_matrix()[:,0], y = cluster1.as_matrix()[:,1], z = cluster1.as_matrix()[:,2],
    color='green', showscale = True
)
cluster2 = dict(
    alphahull = 5,
    name = "Cluster 2",
    opacity = .1,
    type = "mesh3d",    
    x = cluster2.as_matrix()[:,0], y = cluster2.as_matrix()[:,1], z = cluster2.as_matrix()[:,2],
    color='blue', showscale = True
)
cluster3 = dict(
    alphahull = 5,
    name = "Cluster 3",
    opacity = .1,
    type = "mesh3d",    
    x = cluster3.as_matrix()[:,0], y = cluster3.as_matrix()[:,1], z = cluster3.as_matrix()[:,2],
    color='red', showscale = True
)
layout = dict(
    title = 'Interactive Cluster Shapes in 3D',
    scene = dict(
        xaxis = dict(zeroline=True ),
        yaxis = dict(zeroline=True ),
        zaxis = dict(zeroline=True ),
    )
)
fig = dict(data=[scatter1, scatter2, scatter3, cluster1, cluster2, cluster3], layout=layout )
# Use py.iplot() for IPython notebook
plotly.offline.iplot(fig, filename='mesh3d_sample.html')

#py.iplot(fig, filename='mesh3d_sample')
```

HTML with just the axis and no data points displayed
[image]

Comment: Can you share your data, e.g. `df`? Without a [MCVE] it is hard to give an answer.